# How to find a vector of constant $P$ such that $\Lambda' \beta = P' X \beta$?

Tags: matrices, statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, regression-analysis

There is an example in a textbook (without any explanation) on finding $\lambda$, and I am struggling to know how to explicitly find $\rho$ and $\lambda$ such that $\lambda' \beta = \rho'X\beta$, i.e., is estimable function.

In the textbook, "an estimable function, $X\beta$ can be thought of as a vector of inner products between $\beta$ and the spanning set for $C(X')$. In particular when $\lambda$ is $p \times 1$ vector, $\lambda \in C(X')$ i.e., $\lambda = X'\rho$ or more generally, $$\Lambda' \beta = P' X \beta$$ for some matrix $P$.  An important property of estimable functions is that $P$ need not be unique."

Example from the textbook (Simple Linear regression):
$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_x x_i + e_i$, $i = 1\ldots, 6$, where $e_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2_i)$. In matrix form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\ \vdots \\y_6
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 \\
1 & 5 \\
1 & 6
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\ \beta_1
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\ \vdots \\e_6
\end{bmatrix}$$
so that
$$\frac{1}{35}\begin{pmatrix} -5, & -3, & -1,& 1,& 3, & 5 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 \\
1 & 5 \\
1 & 6
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\ \beta_1
\end{bmatrix}  =  
\begin{pmatrix}
0,1 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \beta_0 \\ \beta_1 \end{bmatrix}= \beta_1$$

and

$$\frac{1}{30}\begin{pmatrix} 20, & 14, & 8,& 2,& -4, & -10 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
1 & 3 \\
1 & 4 \\
1 & 5 \\
1 & 6
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\beta_0 \\ \beta_1
\end{bmatrix} 
 = \beta_0$$

Apparently $\rho' = \frac{1}{35}\begin{pmatrix} -5, & -3, & -1,& 1,& 3, & 5 \end{pmatrix}
$ and $\lambda= \begin{pmatrix} 0, 1 \end{pmatrix}$  in the first case and $\rho' = \frac{1}{30}\begin{pmatrix} 20, & 14, & 8,& 2,& -4, & -10 \end{pmatrix}$ in the second case. How can one explicithy find $\rho$ or $P$ even though $\rho$ or $P$ is not unique?

Comment: Your design matrix has full column rank, hence any linear combination $c'\beta$ is estimable, and to get the corresponding $\lambda$, just compute the same linear combination of your two known values of $\lambda$. Or is it a more general question? Then given $c$, you simply have to solve an underdetermined linear system: each dot product of $\lambda$ and a column of the design matrix gives one equation, that is $\lambda'X^{(i)}=c_i$ for all  $i$. You can do that with Gaussian pivoting, and there will be parameters in the solution (since the system is underdetermined).

Comment: This might also help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302015/what-is-the-point-of-introducing-the-concept-of-estimable-function

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Maybe I didn't frame the question well. What I am interested in is knowing how to obtain the $\rho$ vector and the $\lambda$ vector such that $\lambda' \beta = \rho' X \beta$ holds.

Comment: Here's another similar example: One-way ANOVA $y_{ij} = \mu + \alpha_i + e_{ij}$ $\begin{bmatrix}
y_{11} \\ y_{12} \\y_{13}\\y_{21}\\y_{31}\\y_{32}
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu \\ \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \\ \alpha_3
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
e_{11} \\ e_{12} \\e_{13}\\e_{21}\\e_{31}\\e_{32}
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Clearly, $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 2\alpha_3$ is estimable since $X$ is full column rank. Find $\rho'$ such that $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 - 2\alpha_3 = \rho' X \beta$. Even though $\rho'$ is not unique, is there a formal way of finding $\rho$? In text, $\rho' = (1,0,0,1,-2,0)$.

Comment: This $X$ is **not** full column rank (the sum of the 3last column equals the first). However, the method is the same: write the underdetermined linear system and solve it. (after rereading, I see I had the notation wrong, but it doesn't matter: what I called $c$ is your $\lambda$, and what I called $\lambda$ is your $\rho$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117750/discussion-between-holala-and-jean-claude-arbaut).

Comment: The chat seems not to work in math mode. $\lambda = X'\rho \equiv$ $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix} \rho$ and after RREF, the null basis are $\begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatirx}$, $\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatirx}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\0\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatirx}$

Comment: Compute the RREF of the *transposed* design matrix augmented by the column $(0,1,1,-2)^T$. Then you can chose $\lambda$ such that the equations hold. For instance, $\lambda=(1,-1,1,1,-1,-1)$. And you can check that $\lambda X=(0,1,1,-2)$.

Comment: Sorry for the typos. $\lambda = X'\rho \iff \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\1\\-2\end{bmatrix}=X' \rho$ and after RREF, the null basis are 
$\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\\ 0 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \\0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\\ 0 \\ 0 \\-1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ but as you indicated when I checked the coefficients for the estimable function$(0, 1, 1, -2)'$ it seems not right because $\lambda' \beta \not= \rho'X\beta$. I definitely did something wrong.

Comment: Could you cross check and figure out what I am missing out?

Comment: Read my comment above 6 minutes ago. Which equations are you trying to solve? What's the RHS of the system? The RHS is a vector with 4 elements, right? Hence there are 4 equations. Write them, and write the matrix of this system.